# Together Mode in Group Calls Skype for desktop on Windows 11 Pro on my DELL laptop is broken

Tags: windows-11, skype

For some time I have a problem with a Skype installation on Windows 11 Pro.

When I switch the Group Call to **Together Mode** I get a broken result.

[Broken together mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws6Rp.jpg)

I tried to reinstall Skype but it didn't help. Both Skype and Windows seems to be up to date.

I have no idea what to do now.

Did any of you came across similiar issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.